# codeigniter data display yearwise and authorwise and counting

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have following table prpaps [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiLY4.png) in mysql database. I am able to display all the results in view of codeigniter. But how can i display count  for particular year.For example 2016 records (6), 2017 records (2).How can i display count author wise in a year. For example in 2016,aks(2),amit(1),pradeep(3),sanjay(1), shefali(2),arjun(2).I tried a lot but not able to get desired result.
I will be very much grateful if any body help me to write command for
Controller

```
 public function pagination()
        {
          $this->load->model('Sample_model');
          $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test/index.php/welcome/pagination/';

          $config['total_rows'] = $this->Sample_model->count_rows('prlapps');
          $config['per_page'] = 20;
          $config['num_tag_open']='&nbsp &nbsp';
          $config['next_tag_open']='&nbsp &nbsp';
          $config['last_tag_open']='&nbsp &nbsp';
          $config['cur_tag_open']='&nbsp &nbsp';
          $config['prev_tag_open']='&nbsp &nbsp';
          $this->pagination->initialize($config);
          $data['table'] = $this->Sample_model->get_limited_data(20, $this->uri->segment(3));
          $data['view']='pagination_view';
          $this->load->view('load_view',$data);

        }
```

view

```
<?php

echo $this->table->generate($table);
echo $this->pagination->create_links();

 ?>
```

Comment: what u have tried so far? show ur code

Comment: I have added my view and controller.how to count and display in view.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to break this data into a separate authors table. You would end up with the following tables:

1. Books table
2. Authors table
3. Book_Authors_link

Each Author gets their own ID and each book gets its own ID - you then combine them in the Book_Authors_link table and can then join on that table and use Mysql GROUP BY and COUNT(*) to see how many authors did what in each year.